# $G$ has a directed even cycle iff its vertices can be 2-colored so every vertex has an out-neighbor of the other color

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a directed graph, where there's a directed path from every
>   point to every other. How to prove that these two statements are
>   equivalent:
>
> a) Graph $G$ has a directed simple cycle that has even number of edges
>
> b) Graph $G$'s vertices can be painted with two colors (each one with
>   one color) so that for every vertex u, there will be arc $(u,v)$, where
>   v and u are of different colors.

I know that to prove equivalence, I need to prove that a follows from b and b from a. But how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint:

For (a) $ \rightarrow $ (b): pick a vertex in $ v $ that is part of the cycle that has even length, and color him black. Color the remaining vertices white if they are an odd distance away from $ v $, and black if they are an even distance away from $ v $. Check that the property (b) is satisfied.

For (b) $ \rightarrow $ (a): construct a path by starting at an arbitrary vertex and always moving to a neighbor with a different color, and terminating the path when the path intersects itself. Check that the path is even length

Comment: What does "$u$ is an odd distance away from $v$" mean? Does it mean that the distance from $u$ to $v$ is odd, or does it mean that the distance from $v$ to $u$ is odd"?

Comment: Please clarify your hint with an example. Consider the graph with vertices $v,a,b,c,d,e$ and edges $va,ab,bc,cd,de,ev,bv,bd.$ Is vertex $w$ an odd or even distance from $v?$ Is vertex $d$ an odd or even distance from $v?$